# Python Source Code to Interact with Windows 10 Color Themes

Tags: python, windows, themes, registry

Based on this issue:

https://superuser.com/questions/1711880/change-window-frame-color-for-regedit-gvim-and-other-windows/1711990#1711990

I've decided to write an applet to interact with Windows 10 (maybe via the Registry?), and modify and show colors and where you are likely to see them.   For example, I might display common contrasts like you might see on Title Bars, Highlighted text in the Mail and Calendar app, the weird colors in Process Explorer, etc.

I am looking for packages, other applets, etc., to get started.

Here are a couple specific questions such that I hopefully do not create a question that is too vague or opinion-based:

1. How does one interact with the Windows Registry in Python?   (For example, if I wanted to read/write the Keys in Control Panel...Colors)
2. What are the registry items that control colors in Windows 10?    (I am already aware of the ones in Control Panel, and DWM, but a detailed description of how they are used would be great.   For example, AccentColor is apparently "randomly" updated by the OS all the time.)

Comment: Please have a look at (1) https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/winreg.html and (2) https://superuser.com/questions/1245923/registry-keys-to-change-personalization-settings

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you, so much!   Not sure why these didn't turn up in my searches--must be something inside?  (Adam Ant, lol).   I am surprised this applet is not already available somewhere though.   It would be great to start with some open-source code somewhere. 
  Maybe I am also not searching well for such an app?   I found stuff like this:  "https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/how+to+detect+system+dark+mode," and a few similar such examples in Python, and that's about it.   Anyway, if you care to put your suggestions into answer form, I would be happy to accept them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have deeper insight or a solution but the following links might help:

Python documentation for `winreg` module: [winreg — Windows registry access](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/winreg.html%20(winreg%20%E2%80%94%20Windows%20registry%20access))

Deals with tweaking Windows through registry settings: [Are Windows 10 Personalization settings available in Registry?](https://superuser.com/questions/1295855/are-windows-10-personalization-settings-available-in-registry?rq=1)

[The Python Package Index (PyPI) is a repository of software for the Python programming language.](https://pypi.org/)